# Word for taking users/consumers away from another

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase to describe the act of *taking consumers away* from one existing standard/norm in favor of an alternative.

For example: 3D printing will *take away* consumers from manufacturers and put the manufacturing into individuals hands.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"win over" or "convert".

3D printing will **win over** consumers and put the manufacturing into individuals hands.

Comment: I like convert. In the sense that 3D printing will convert consumers into becoming their own manufacturers.

Answer (score 8):

> [poach](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poach) — 2c:  to attract (as an employee or customer) away from a competitor

3D printers are *poaching* customers from manufacturers.

Comment: I think poaching is most commonly used in the industries I have been involved with.

Comment: The term *poaching* is used where there is a policy or tradition to not do that, just like in hunting, where poaching is hunting in prohibited areas. It doesn't apply here. Poaching is a nefarious and deplorable practice. There is no such connotation here. And machinery can't poach.

Answer (score 3):

Before winning them, they must be [lured](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/lure) to or [enticed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/entice?s=t) by your product: to **attract**, or tempt; allure; to draw by appealing to the emotions or senses, by stimulating interest, or by exciting admiration; allure; invite: to attract attention; to attract admirers by one's charm.

> Aptus's U.S. clinical study of the product **lured** some top vascular doctors, including study co-directors Ronald M. Fairman, a University of Pennsylvania vascular surgery professor, and vascular surgeon Manish Mehta of Albany Medical Center in New York. - WSJ
>
> ...purchases are based off of appearance, and whether or not the consumer buys a product depends on if the appearance of the product **enticed** them enough. - courseportfolio.org

Comment: Those are really great! +1

Answer (score 2):

> [Cannibalization marketing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannibalization_%28marketing%29)
>
> In marketing strategy, cannibalization refers to a reduction in sales volume, sales 
>   revenue, or market share of one product as a result of the introduction of a new product by 
>   the same producer.

Comment: That's great to know. Thanks. I work in IT at an ad agency and I'll now feel more knowledgeable when talking about this kind of thing.

Comment: This question  isn't about cannibalization. Note the part about "same producer" in the definition.

Comment: @PhilSweet Ever hear of the [Osborne effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Osborne_effect), that was just the announcement of a new product from the same producer.

Answer (score 2):

Where I work, we use the phrase "stealing market share."

Answer (score 0):

Here are some alternatives:

3D printing will **steer consumers away** from manufacturers and put the manufacturing into individuals hands.

3D printing **channel influence away** from manufacturers and into individuals hands.

3D printing will **sway consumers away** from manufacturers and put the manufacturing into individuals hands.

Also, the word "dissuade" might be applicable somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I like *poaching* best, already answered, but depending on context you might try **parasitising**.